# WPF control template : why TargetType is required where its obvious?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am a bit puzzled by the excessive verbosity of xaml in wpf. For e.g. when defining a control template, you still have to specify the target type as the control itself. Is specifying the TargetType necessary ? Since I am defining the template element of TargetControl does it not default to the TargetControl when not specified?

```
<local:TargetControl Width="100" Height="100">
 <local:TargetControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TargetControl">
      <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="PART_Target" Fill="Blue" />
      <Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
 </local:TargetControl.Template>
</local:TargetControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

markup `<ControlTemplate> </ControlTemplate>` means that new ControlTemplate instance is create using default constructor (`new ControlTemplate()`). The constructor is not aware which element will use the template.

in this example

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TargetControl">
  <Grid>
    <Ellipse x:Name="PART_Target" Fill="Blue" />
  <Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

template can be used without TargetType because it doesn't use any `TargetControl`-specific properties for `TemplateBinding`s. If TemplateBindings are required, TargetType also has to be set.

in most cases element template has the same TargetType as the type of element.

But there can be exeptional cases, e.g.: I want my RadioButtons and CheckBoxes look like colored circles - green when Checked and gray when Unchecked.

RadioButton and CheckBox derive from ToggleButton, so I create template for ToggleButton and apply to my RadioButtons and CheckBoxes:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="Toggle">
            <Border Name="btn" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gainsboro"
                    Width="28" Height="28" CornerRadius="14" />

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="btn" Value="Lime" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <CheckBox Template="{StaticResource Toggle}" />
    <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource Toggle}" />
    <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource Toggle}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

this example also demonstrates the situation when ControlTemplate is defined in resource dictionary without connection to specific element, so TargetType cannot be inferred.

so there are at least 3 cases when TargetType is not known for certain or not needed. So it is left to developers to always provide concrete type